Jest complains that I am console.log'ing after a test is completed
I have the following function:
function procedure() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject("MyExcept");
        }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Some message");
        }, 10000);
    });
}

And I am testing it using Jest like so:
describe('test function', function () {
    it('throws MyExcept', async function () {
        expect.assertions(1);
        await expect(procedure()).rejects.toBe("MyExcept");
    }, 6000);
});

This test is passed by Jest.  However a few seconds later, when procedure() attempts to console.log() again, Jest complains:

Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

In the above example, we can see how long it's going to take for the console.log() to happen, but in my real, more complex scenario, it could take a long time (in reality, it's waiting for a socket to clear up).  I want that console.log() to still happen at some point after the rejection, so that's good, but also want this test to be considered passed when the rejection happens, and for things to move on.
What can I do?  Is there some way I can tell jest to just kill everything that was invoked by the call when the test is over (timers, or anything else)?
This is node 20.11.0

There is no way for Jest or any other piece of code to determine that this async code (timeout 10s) belongs to a specific test and prevent it from being executed. You can use --forceExit in case you believe it's unavoidable. But this actually means that testability is flawed, tested unit (procedure) needs to provide proper cleanup logic to run it in tests. If it's a socket, it's supposed to be a function that closes it
